# wifi keeps dropping in 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I've got Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a Lenovo Thinkpad T410.  I've recently noticed a problem where every night after the laptop hasn't been used for a while, the wifi drops.  At first it seemed to go into a power save mode so I tried disabling power save on the wifi adapter with:

```
sudo sed -i "s/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/g" /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

and it seemed to work, but for the last few days the problem changed to where the wifi icon gets a question mark on it and I have to turn wifi off and back on for it to connect.

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 35
       serial: 58:94:6b:d9:ac:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-58-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=10.0.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:f2400000-f2401fff

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

any suggestions on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*`. Try this in terminal and restart the network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart` and if this doesn't work then go to wifi settings and then disable ipv6 and then restart the network manager with the same command. Hope this works.

Comment: Did it worked? @zenjim

Comment: tried this.  I'll know if it worked after the laptop sits for a day.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved a similar problem with Centrino wireless devices in the past:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8 swcrypto=1 power_save=0"
```

Then restart `iwlwifi` with:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi
sudo service network-manager restart
```

What this does:

| Command | Action |
| --- | --- |
| `11n_disable=8` | Enables agg TX option |
| `swcrypto=1` | Disables hardware encryption and uses software instead. |
| `power_save=0` | Disables the power save mode |

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I ran 'sudo modprobe -r iwldvm iwlwifi' I got the error 'rmmod: ERROR: missing module name.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi'
and wifi disappeared from ubuntu.  Had to reboot to get it back